# Backup script and move files to another server

Tags: linux, debian

I want to create a `.sh` script to backup my data and move to my backup server.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does your update-server support NFS? I use a small self-crafted script at home to do the job. But it relies on NFS to be set up on the server...

Comment: I think not! I'm know the basic of the basic about linux (apt-get update package-that-I-want) other things, I always searching,

Comment: Is your update server in your home network? Do you have access to your server via SSH and is the server a Debian machine as well as your Desktop PC from which you want to make your backups?

Comment: Please provide more details or otherwise your question will get closed soon for missing important details, causing it to be too broad to be answered properly.

Answer (score 2):

If your backup-server has ssh then use scp to copy over the files e.g.

```
scp -r /src/folder user@server:/path/
```

(-r flag to copy entire directory instead of a single)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using rsync, as after the initial backup it only needs to modify files that have changed since the last execution.  If you have configured your backup target for ssh, the following will work:

rsync -avz --delete -e ssh /path/to/your/data/ your-backup-server.com:/path/to/save/your/data/

Note that rsync is particular about how you name things; /path/data/ yourserver.com:/path/data/ will copy the contents of /path/data/ exactly to /path/data/.  Please review the man pages for rsync for a better understanding.